# mysql table views with conditions

Tags: mysql, database, architecture

I have an online store, two views because my products could come from either my packages table or sessions table. The prices are joined from the price table.

The two views work fine on their own, but when I combine there usage I get no results. 
I want my shipping guy to only see the items he should ship, not the digital items, namely, those with delivery format equal to 'DVD'.

session view:

```
select 
        `ats_store`.`order`.`payment_type` AS `payment_type`,
        `production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`createdOn` AS `order_date`,
        `production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`FIRSTNAME` AS `firstname`,
        `production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`LASTNAME` AS `lastname`,
        `ats_store`.`order`.`id` AS `order_id`,
        `ats_store`.`order`.`customerid` AS `customerid`,
        `ats_store`.`order`.`shipping_address_id` AS `shipping_address_id`,
        `ats_store`.`order`.`status` AS `status`,
        `ats_store`.`order_items`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`country` AS `country`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`street_1` AS `street1`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`street_2` AS `street2`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`street_3` AS `street3`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`city` AS `city`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`state_and_province` AS `state`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`zip_code` AS `zip`,
        group_concat(`production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_conference_session__c`.`Name`,
            '(',
            `price`.`Delivery_Format__c`,
            ')'
            order by `production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_conference_session__c`.`sort_code__c` ASC
            separator ',') AS `session_products`
    from
        (((((`ats_store`.`order`
        left join `ats_store`.`shipping_address` ON ((`ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`id` = `ats_store`.`order`.`shipping_address_id`)))
        join `ats_store`.`order_items` ON ((`ats_store`.`order_items`.`order_id` = `ats_store`.`order`.`id`)))
        join `production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_store_price__c` `price` ON ((`price`.`Id` = `ats_store`.`order_items`.`product_id`)))
        join `production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_conference_session__c` ON ((`production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_conference_session__c`.`Id` = convert( `price`.`ATS_Conference_Session__c` using utf8))))
        left join `production_www`.`paypal_transactions` ON ((`production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`id` = `ats_store`.`order`.`paypal_transaction_id`)))
    where
        ((`ats_store`.`order`.`shipping_address_id` <> -(1))
            and (`production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`COMMENT1` = 'ATS Web Store')
            and (`production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`RESPMSG` = 'Approved')
            and (`price`.`Delivery_Format__c` = 'DVD'))
    group by `ats_store`.`order`.`id`
    order by `production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`createdOn`
```

package view:

```
select 
        `ats_store`.`order`.`payment_type` AS `payment_type`,
        `production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`createdOn` AS `order_date`,
        `production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`FIRSTNAME` AS `firstname`,
        `production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`LASTNAME` AS `lastname`,
        `ats_store`.`order`.`id` AS `order_id`,
        `ats_store`.`order`.`customerid` AS `customerid`,
        `ats_store`.`order`.`shipping_address_id` AS `shipping_address_id`,
        `ats_store`.`order`.`status` AS `status`,
        `ats_store`.`order_items`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`country` AS `country`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`street_1` AS `street1`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`street_2` AS `street2`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`street_3` AS `street3`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`city` AS `city`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`state_and_province` AS `state`,
        `ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`zip_code` AS `zip`,
        `price`.`Delivery_Format__c` AS `delivery_format`,
        group_concat(`production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_store_package__c`.`Package_Code__c`,
            '(',
            `price`.`Delivery_Format__c`,
            ')'
            order by `production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_store_package__c`.`Package_Code__c` ASC
            separator ',') AS `package_products`
    from
        (((((`ats_store`.`order`
        left join `ats_store`.`shipping_address` ON ((`ats_store`.`shipping_address`.`id` = `ats_store`.`order`.`shipping_address_id`)))
        join `ats_store`.`order_items` ON ((`ats_store`.`order_items`.`order_id` = `ats_store`.`order`.`id`)))
        join `production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_store_price__c` `price` ON ((`price`.`Id` = `ats_store`.`order_items`.`product_id`)))
        join `production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_store_package__c` ON ((`production_cache_salesforce_repl`.`ats_store_package__c`.`Id` = convert( `price`.`ATS_Store_Package__c` using utf8))))
        left join `production_www`.`paypal_transactions` ON ((`production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`id` = `ats_store`.`order`.`paypal_transaction_id`)))
    where
        ((`ats_store`.`order`.`shipping_address_id` <> -(1))
            and (`production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`COMMENT1` = 'ATS Web Store')
            and (`production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`RESPMSG` = 'Approved')
            and (`price`.`Delivery_Format__c` = 'DVD'))
    group by `ats_store`.`order`.`id`
    order by `production_www`.`paypal_transactions`.`createdOn`
```

Here is the query that uses both views:

```
select *,group_concat(pv.package_products,',',sv.session_products) as products from ats_store.shipping_orders_sessions_view sv,ats_store.shipping_orders_packages_view pv
where sv.order_id = pv.order_id
group by sv.order_id
```

If I remove from the VIEWS `and (`price`.`Delivery_Format__c`= 'DVD')` I can get the orders, but the digital and DVD products are shown. I only want my shipping guy to see items he should ship, the DVDs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your two views are clean and working:

Let's work on that query that joins them.

Here's what you have, rewritten to use an explicit join.

```
select *,         /* query with problems */
       group_concat(pv.package_products,',',sv.session_products) as products
  from ats_store.shipping_orders_sessions_view sv
  join ats_store.shipping_orders_packages_view pv on sv.order_id = pv.order_id
 group by sv.order_id
```

What's wrong here?

First, pro tip: don't use `select *` in complex queries.

Second, `select *` guarantees random nonsense in your output resultset because you're using a harmful nonstandard MySQL hackstension. Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html  You should mention each non-aggregated column in your result set in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Third, you probably want

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(pv.package_products,',',sv.session_product)) AS products
```

to make sure you are using the aggregating function `GROUP_CONCAT()` properly.

So here is a better query.

```
select sv.order_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(pv.package_products,',',sv.session_product)) AS products
  from ats_store.shipping_orders_sessions_view sv
  join ats_store.shipping_orders_packages_view pv on sv.order_id = pv.order_id
 group by sv.order_id
```

**EDIT**:  This will yield a result set with one row per distinct `order_id` that mentions all the products in each order. If you wish to include only certain items, for example those with delivery_format = 'DVD', you need to add a WHERE clause.  It looks like your package view exposes that column.  So try this:

```
select sv.order_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(pv.package_products,',',sv.session_product)) AS products
  from ats_store.shipping_orders_sessions_view sv
  join ats_store.shipping_orders_packages_view pv on sv.order_id = pv.order_id
 where pv.delivery_format = 'DVD'
 group by sv.order_id
```

I don't understand your schema well enough to give you better advice than this. I can see that your views are quite complex.

Comment: Thank you! But I still get proucts that are not DVDs. I want to get only DVDs, because my shipping guy should only see those. great explanations!